# Import single subroutine from perl program

Tags: perl, perl-module

Is there a way to import/export a single subroutine from a Perl script.  I have been asked to split test cases into positive and negative tests, and I don't want to copy entire subroutines.  But if I `require` or `use` the positive test case from the negative, I get a `redefined` warning for all of the commonly named subs.  Here are a few alternatives that I have tried:

```
require/use "positive_test.pl" qw (useful_sub);
#throws warning: Subroutine run_test redefined at ...

require/use "positive_test.pl::useful_sub";
#throws can't locate in @INC error
```

and from the positive_test script:

```
use base 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw(useful_sub);
```

I have also tried use and require from within a new subroutine namespace.  What am I missing, or do I have to wrap every common module name within a no warnings 'redefine' wrapper?  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably best is: do some refactoring. Create a new .pm file which contains all the subs you want to export.

Of course it's possible with Perl to hack around these issues without refactoring. For example, you could switch to another package before calling require:

```
{
    package AnotherPackage;
    require "positive_test.pl";
}

AnotherPackage::useful_test();
```

Note that in this case you don't need the Exporter at all.

Comment: I did have to do some refactoring.  The solution you provided works well in limited instances, but factors like Perl's `require` only being able to load a single instance where too difficult to work around